# Powershell 7 - Get-ADUser or Get-ADObject not returning all values for the multivalue "objectClass" property

Tags: powershell, active-directory, multivalue

Our domain users have person,organizationalPerson,user, and top values in the objectClass property for each user account. Some may have posixAccount as an additional value. Get-ADUser and Get-ADObject only return "user" for objectClass, even if the LDAPFilter is specifically set to objectClass=posixAccount.

Is there some other command or method to retrieve all of the values for objectClass?

```
E:\(Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter (&(objectClass=top)(name=xxxx))).objectClass
user
E:\(Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter (&(objectClass=person)(name=xxxx))).objectClass
user
E:\(Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(name=xxxx))).objectClass
user
```

Comment: Try querying for objectCategory instead of objectClass

Comment: That just returns the DN for the schema item for "Person".

Comment: Try : Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter (&(objectClass=top)(name=xxxx)) | Select-Object -Property *

Comment: Try `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=posixAccount)(name=xxxx))`